# Restore SQL database from disc copy backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have managed to drop an SQL express 2008 database, that I accessed using SQL Management studio.

I don't have a backup of the database created through Management Studio or SQL, but I do have a disc copy of my entire `c:` drive made prior to a machine rebuild 4 weeks ago (A previous installation of the dropped database did exist at this stage). The disc backup contains all the databases (2) and versions, that I require.

Can I restore the databases from copies of raw files form a backup disc?  If so is this complicated?
Which files would I need to be copy and to where?

Thanks in advance. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty easy:

1. (if needed) re-install SQL Server (Express) - you should make sure to install the version **with** the Management Studio
2. Copy the "raw" files (`*.mdf` and `*.ldf`) to the default data directory
3. In SQL Server Management Studio (Express), in the Object Explorer, go to the `Database` node and right-click and pick `Attach...`
4. Find your `*.mdf` file in question and select it

That should be all there is!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the old .mdf and .ldf files you can use the "attach database" option rather than restore.